# How to sort a merged querysets Django

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to combine multiple SQL queries into a single query, and then sort the merged query by a date field

```
datas = None
for product in products:
    if datas is not None:
        datas = datas | Data.objects.filter(product=product)
    else:
        datas = Data.objects.filter(product=product)

datas = datas.all().order_by('created_on')
```

Current result is that each "data set" is "sorted by the created_on field" and they appear one below the other. So essentially sorting is by Product Name, and then by created_on field

but what I want is the combined "datasets" to be sorted as one by just the "created on field".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to use an [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) here:

```
datas = Data.objects.filter(product__in=products).order_by('created_on')
```

This will not only work correctly, it is more compact and self-explaining.